# Dynamic update of visual components in swing

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

I have a question regarding the possibility to dinamically update the visual side of a swing application. 
I have created a small program, that works without any compile/logic errors and it does it's thing but it has a flaw. It does not automatically update when user clicks on something. 
Let me explain the issue with the underneath picture

[image]

I tried adding a repaint and revalidate to anything. but it doesn't seem to work. they get ignored. Really, I added a repaint/revalidate method to EVERYTHING. Still nothing :)

Comment: Post your question as text, not an image.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest adding the action event to the checkbox (I called it `fullAutomaticCheckBox` and the field `txtField`):

```
private void fullAutomaticCheckBoxActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                      
    txtField.setEnabled(fullAutomaticCheckBox.isSelected());
}
```

To add the event listener:

```
    fullAutomaticCheckBox.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            fullAutomaticCheckBoxActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want the text field to enable itself.

Then you add an ActionListener to the check box to enable/disable the text field depending on the state of the checkbox.

> once user inputs a number it will repaint dynamically

If you want the screen to repaint, then you need to invoke the "update calculations" code dynamically. So you can add a `DocumentListener` to the text field. This will generate an event any time the user adds or removes text in the text field.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Write a DocumentListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html) for a basic example to get you started.